# How to display an array of json objects in the dom via .append()

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

So I have an array that's being pulled from a json object that I'd like to display as images in a div called #practice:

```
["<img src ="http://domain.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/random04-128x84.jpg"/>", 

"<img src ="http://domain.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/chuck_norris_random_fact_generator_6_3957_2224_image_2578-128x84.jpg"/>"]
```

Here is the method I have so far...

```
$.getJSON('wp-content/themes/invoke-dmd/get-client-logos.php/', function (data) {
    var items = [];
    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
        items.push('<img src ="' + val.url + '"/>');
    });
  console.log(items)
  $('#practice').append(items);
});
```

It logs out the array as above... but cannot show it in the div.

How does one do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
$.getJSON('wp-content/themes/invoke-dmd/get-client-logos.php/', function (data) {

    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
        $('#practice').append('<img src ="' + val.url + '"/>');
    });

});
```

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to add the images HTML as an array, you need to add a string:

```
$('#practice').append(items.join(" "));
```